# Cumulative sum of trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals, time-series, trigonometric-series

I have two known time series $ Y,  $

$Y = \left\{ Y_i  \right\}_N  \hspace {0.2 in}  Y_i > 0 \hspace {0.2 in}  -1  \leq Y_{i+1} - Y_i   \leq 1 $ for all $i$

$ = \left\{ _i  \right\}_N  $

Let us define the time series $φ$  as:

\begin{equation}   y_j =  Y_{j+1} - Y_j    \hspace {0.2 in}   y_j = cos(φ_j + _j)      \hspace {0.2 in}      φ = \left\{ φ_i  \right\}_N \hspace {0.2 in}    \end{equation}

then \begin{equation} Y_{i+1} - Y_0 = \sum_{j=0}^{j=i}cos(φ_j + _j)          \end{equation}

and \begin{equation} Y_{i+1} - Y_0 = \sum_{j=0}^{j=i}cos(φ_j)cos(_j)  - \sum_{j=0}^{j=i}sin(φ_j)sin( _j)      \end{equation}

After plotting  I found that the charts of

\begin{equation} \sum_{j=0}^{j=i}cos(φ_j)  \hspace {0.2 in} \sum_{j=0}^{j=i}sin(φ_j)      \end{equation}

are the same respectively to
\begin{equation} \sum_{j=0}^{j=i}sin(_j)  \hspace {0.2 in} \sum_{j=0}^{j=i}cos(_j)      \end{equation}

How is it possible?

Comment: For the "After plotting the charts part," it's confusing as to what is equal to what

Comment: i can not use the equal symbol that is why i wrote " are the same respectively to" instead.